# Getting PR information in the jenkins pipeline

Tags: email, jenkins, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket and jenkins as my CI/CD solution.
I am running a sanity job everytime Pull request is raised. I want to send email notification on the success or failure of the job to the owner of the pull requuest. The challenge I am facing is I am not able to get the user information for the PR in jenkins pipeline.

Anybody has solved this porblem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach to this: instead of directly emailing the author of the PR, use the Bitbucket API to write a comment on the PR ([doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-pull-request-id-comments-post)). Since you would already have the PR ID, it's just a matter of sending a POST request.

By default, any comments written on a Bitbucket PR automatically trigger an email to the PR author + PR reviewers so they will be getting notified via email as well.

Comment: Thats an interesting approach. Let me try that.